# Retrieve the array from function variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How do I retrieve `this` from a previous function?

```
function bla(my_array) {
        image_tag[this] = $('<img src="'+ random_url +'"/>');
        image_tag[this].appendTo('body');
        image_tag[this].bind('load', function () {
            alert('this'); //instead of alerting "image_tag[4]", I'd like to alert its array "4"   
        });
    });
}

bla(4);
```

Comment: We have no idea what the array is, what `this` is, what `image_tag` is, what `my_array` is or what the frack you're trying to do ?

Comment: Why would you set this to 4?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, I didn't include the whole code because I thought it would confuse things even more.

Comment: In your sample code, `this` will refer to the `window`, and the value of `my_array` will be `4`.

Comment: Is my question clearer now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $.proxy to bind your previous "this" to the new function:

```
image_tag[this].load($.proxy(function() {
    alert(this);
},this));
```

Comment: That worked! I see you have changed `bind.('load'` to just `load`, may I ask you what the difference is?

Comment: .load is just a short hand for .bind("load") -- jQuery has quite a few (like .click, .keyup, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your sample code works the way you think it does: http://jsfiddle.net/eSwf7/

But assuming that in your actual code, everything works fine and you just want to refer to `this` from the outer function inside the click handler, you can do this:

```
function bla(my_array) {
    var that = this;
    image_tag[this].bind('load', function () {
        alert(that); //instead of alerting "image_tag[4], I'd like to alert 4   
    });
}
```